# Different iOS application settings in debug/release configuration?

Tags: debugging, ios, settings, release

I'm developing an app for the iPad and I have recently added a few settings (like a debug mode switch and an FPS counter switch) to the app's page in Settings.app to make the life of the app testers easier. Of course I don't want to keep these settings there in the final release. Is there a way to hide some of the settings in Settings.bundle in the released version but show them in the debug version? Or, alternatively, is there a way to conditionally use a different Settings.bundle in my app target depending on whether I'm using the release or the debug configuration for compiling the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, in the project build settings, define a C preprocessor macro specific to each configuration. For example, I have `-DDEBUG` in debug configuration, which defines the `DEBUG` macro. Then, code can be conditionaly compiled with `#ifdef DEBUG ... #endif`.

Also, the Info.plist file can be preprocessed.

Comment: In the end, I decided to add a Run Script build phase to the target which preprocesses the Info.plist file. I can get the name of the configuration from the environment variables and use that to decide which parts of the Info.plist file have to be included/excluded. I'll post a full solution here once I sorted it out properly.

Comment: Info.plist preprocessing is part of the official capabilities of XCode (see http://www.leegillen.com/Public/Blog/Entries/2008/6/26_How_to_have_a_target_or_build_configuration_specific_Info.plist.html)

Answer (score 6):

I know this to late, but this may help other people

This is how i solved same problem

- Create 2 Root.plist file one for Debug and one for Release.
- Add this Run script in your build process.

```
 if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ];then
    rm -f "$SRCROOT/Settings.bundle/Root.plist"
    cp "$SRCROOT/Debug/Root.plist" "$SRCROOT/Settings.bundle" 
else
    rm -f "$SRCROOT/Settings.bundle/Root.plist"
    cp "$SRCROOT/Release/Root.plist" "$SRCROOT/Settings.bundle"
```